# Meaning of "-oid" in mathematical concepts?

Tags: terminology

Some mathematical concepts are ended with "-oid", such as Matroid, greedoid, groupoid. What does that mean? Do these concepts share something in common? Thanks!

Comment: i know [humanoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanoid) means a robot

Comment: It's not specifically math terminology. See [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-oid).

Comment: @DavidMitra: Groupoid is like group, and matroid is like ..., and Greedoid is like ...?

Comment: Matrix and, um, Greedo from Star Wars?

Comment: Hopefully the string hemorrh never makes into the mathematical lexicon.

Comment: It’s something like “something like”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Means "bed", "incomplet","deficient" or "weak". For exemple: Grupoid is a algebric struture  "deficient" that is quase a  Group.

Comment: Is it like [quasi-, semi-, pseudo-](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19474/pseudo-quasi-semi-and)?

Comment: @Elias, a groupoid is a category in which all arrows are iso. This includes the category $\bf Group$ , which is a monoid (ie, one-object) groupoid. See: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/groupoid

Comment: @Elias, - just wanted to clarify, groupoids are generalizations of groups, but in what way are they deficient or quasi? (There's an interesting if cryptic remark in Lawvere & Rosebrugh's *Set Theory for Mathematics* to the effect that most of what we know about groups carries over to groupoids.)

Comment: Sounds a lot like "-ish."  Such a shame we didn't end up with matrish or groupish.

Comment: @JesseMadnick, Good +1.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a "center" of an object, it means "equidistant" from the edges (spacially).

If you have a [**centroid**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid), it means the **weighted** "center" of an object, where the weightS are something like the density of the material.

Here the "oid" is a reference to the "weighted" (e.g. center) property, not the literal one.